# Spring JPA - method "getById" is not working, I get null

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get object by ID, but I can't figure it out , why i get null and it isn`t working..

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "exercises")
public class ExerciseEntity {

@Id
private Long id;
private String nameOfExercise;
private Integer caloriesBurnedForHour;
@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String bonusInfo;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "exerciseEntityList",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<PersonalTrainingProgram> personalTrainingPrograms;

public ExerciseEntity() {
}


@Entity
public class PersonalTrainingProgram {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable()
private List<ExerciseEntity> exerciseEntityList;
@ManyToOne
private FoodProgram foodProgram;
@ManyToOne
private AppUser appUser;

public PersonalTrainingProgram() {
}
```

And here is the method,

```
@Override
public List<ExerciseEntity> findExercisesBySpecificId(List<ExerciseDto> exerciseDto) {

    List<ExerciseEntity> listEntity= new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i <exerciseDto.size() ; i++) {
        ExerciseEntity byId = exercisesRepository.getById(exerciseDto.get(i).getId());
        listEntity.add(byId);
    }
    return listEntity;
}

@Override
public void addItToDatabase(List<ExerciseDto> exerciseDto, FoodProgramDto 
foodProgramDto,String username) {
 PersonalTrainingProgram personalTrainingProgram = new PersonalTrainingProgram();
 personalTrainingProgram.setExerciseEntityList(findExercisesBySpecificId(exerciseDto));
 personalTrainingProgram.setFoodProgram(foodProgramService
.findFoodProgramById(foodProgramDto));
 personalTrainingProgram.setAppUser(appUserRepository.findByUsername(username).get());
personalTrainingRepository.save(personalTrainingProgram);

}
```

After exercise line on debug mode i get this "  {ExerciseEntity$HibernateProxy$B...}"
I think it can be possibly from relationship, but everything seems fine to me. Any help would be appreciate

Repository is standard repository, extending JPA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use `findById` that returns an Optional.

getById returns not an entity but a reference.

From the documentation:

> Returns a reference to the entity with the given identifier. Depending
> on how the JPA persistence provider is implemented this is very likely
> to always return an instance and throw an EntityNotFoundException on
> first access. Some of them will reject invalid identifiers
> immediately.

So it's always a proxy that may not be initialized and causes the problem

Comment: Lol, I feel so stupid, what an amateur mistake, thank you very much !